# What "language" is this (found in a .csv file, maybe former excel sheet)?

Tags: php, arrays, excel, csv

I found this in a .csv file (maybe former excel sheet) and want to know what "language" this is:

```
a:6:{i:0;a:2:{s:3:"day";s:6:"Montag";s:7:"opening";s:11:"9:30 - 7:00";}
i:1;a:2:{s:3:"day";s:8:"Dienstag";s:7:"opening";s:11:"9:30 - 7:00";}
i:2;a:2:{s:3:"day";s:8:"Mittwoch";s:7:"opening";s:11:"9:30 - 7:00";}
i:3;a:2:{s:3:" ...
```

As i have to work with this data in a PHP context, i would like to read about the official syntax first, better than guessing how this is done ;)

Comment: Just to make it clear: I know that this is not a real language, but the headline needs to be simple and clear. How would you call this ?

Comment: read the @Phantom answer, he is right!

Comment: @AviAtion There is no such thing as "scv" format. You mean .csv !? And no, i have said .csv in the headline and in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a "language". This is serialized data created with php function serialize(). You can deserialize() it.